# Django project not recognizing SCSS files

Tags: python, django, sass, less

I've been struggling to get Django to recognize my SCSS files (I may be misusing SCSS/SASS/LESS terminology... their relationship confuses me).  I'm using `django-libsass` and `compress`, both of which seem pretty straight-forward.  My page is giving me the error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: ".  It's loading the page but none of my styles are showing.

I'm not sure what people need to see.  My template includes:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/blog.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

(this worked fine when it was css)

Settings:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # other finders..
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `type="text/x-scss"` to the link element along with the compress tag:

```
{% compress css %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/blog.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/x-scss">
{% endcompress %}
```

And make sure to load the compress tag before you use it:

```
{% load compress %}
```

Comment: Ugh.  Duh.  Thanks.